# A word for the state of a object which does not work

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

I want to describe a state of a object of not being functional and being not likely to work normally unless being fixed. How do i describe it? Is break implys that something physically breaks into pieces, and it can not describe electronic devices which do not work anymore?
 Thank you very much!

Comment: The object can be described as being *broken*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such an object is often described as *broken* or as *having failed*. Other possibilities are *busted*, *unserviceable, faulty* or simply *in need of repair.*

These terms can all refer to non-functioning electronic devices, and none of them necessarily imply that the object has been physically smashed or damaged. Electronic components or devices are especially likely to be described as *having failed.*

The *failure rate* of a particular type of equipment may be included in its test specifications (often quoted as the *MTBF*, or *mean time between failures*).

Comment: Also "kaput",  "on the fritz", "out of commission", "dead", "inoperable", or "fried" (if some part literally burned out; i.e., failed from overheating)

Comment: @BrianHitchcock - If we're aiming for completeness, then I suppose we should also include slangier or cruder terms like *shot, buggered, knackered, fucked* and *screwed*.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is very clear. For example, my mp3 player is broken or it has failed. In my opinion, I think having failed is more formal, broken is neutral, and busted is more colloquial?

Comment: @Superuser - Yes, that seems correct to me.

Answer (score 1):

[Out of order](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/out+of+order) is another common expression:

> - Fig. [of something] incapable of operating; [of something] broken. The elevator is out of order again. My stereo is out of order.

Comment: This is what I thought when I read the question.